# Bower: Add local folder content as dependency in bower.json

Tags: windows, filesystems, bower

I have a local folder `D:\MyFolder` where I have a bower package (one min.js, some images in \images folder, and a bower.json). It is not a git repository, just a folder with the package contents. In a second project, I want to add this package as a bower dependency. How can I do that so that on running `bower install` from the second project directory, the contents from MyFolder gets added along with its transitive bower dependencies? If required, I may put it in a zip file, like .tar.gz or something, but it will reside in my local filesystem from where the second project will add it.

Comment: The local package is not a git repository, just a folder.

Comment: Ok, I removed the possible duplicated, once it can't be a git repo.